# CSS div containers width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So check out the "About Us" and "Contact Us" pages [here](http://www.juice-engineering.co.uk/about-us.html).

I'm having some difficulty in getting my DIV containers to align properly.  I've never used DIV containers - last time I made a website it was based on tables and used Golive!

Anyway, the question should be fairly obvious - I want a 250x250 image on the left with the words to the right of the image and wrapping down below it (x3).  The whole lot should be centred in the middle of the page with a max width of 1170 px.  I just can't work out where it's gone wrong.

Likewise on the Contact Us page my 3 DIV containers are aligned vertically rather than across the screen taking up 33% each.  All looks great in Dreamweaver live view but doesn't work in Chrome once uploaded.

I bet it's something simple but I really have no clue!  I'll be super grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Oliver! Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and, regarding the composition of your first question here, also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: @Oliver check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here in the below line of HTML

the div corresponding to **Aviation & Automotive**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 templatemo_col12 templatemo_margintop10">
```

Replace that entire div using this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 templatemo_col12 templatemo_margintop10">
        <div class="item project-post">
            <div class="templatemo_about_box">
                <div class="square_coner">
                    <span class="texts-a"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></span>
                </div>
                Aviation &amp; Automotive
            </div>
            <a href="about-us.html"></a><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 hover-box">
                <a href="about-us.html"></a>
                <div class="inner-hover-box">
                    <p>Repairs, maintenance and add-ons.  We specialise in one-off projects.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]